# page.html.twig default regions

Tags: theming, 8

I'm creating a custom theme with `base theme: stable`. I have copied the `template/layout/page.html.twig` file into my theme. As I am reading the twig file I have noticed that there are some regions that I am not providing but are still being rendered.

Part of the file comment lists the regions available.

```
/*
 * Regions:
 * - page.header: Items for the header region.
 * - page.primary_menu: Items for the primary menu region.
 * - page.secondary_menu: Items for the secondary menu region.
 * - page.highlighted: Items for the highlighted content region.
 * - page.help: Dynamic help text, mostly for admin pages.
 * - page.content: The main content of the current page.
 * - page.sidebar_first: Items for the first sidebar.
 * - page.sidebar_second: Items for the second sidebar.
 * - page.footer: Items for the footer region.
 * - page.breadcrumb: Items for the breadcrumb region.
 */
```

I went looking in the stable.info.yml file and noticed there is not an entry for `regions:` so I am at a loss as how the `page.html.twig` file is able to render regions that are not listed in the `stable.info.yml` file.

**Questions**

- How does this work without being defined in the `stable.info.yml` file.
- Are there any other regions that work like this that are not in the `page.html.twig` file.

Comment: From what I recall, if no regions are specified in the theme, the core provides defaults itself. I could be wrong though.

Comment: You are correct I just found documentation on it.

Comment: Okay, adding as an answer then.

Comment: Sorry didn't realize you were responding with an answer down below. I went ahead and marked yours as the answer since you were the first to find it. Thanks again!! @Kevin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If no regions are specified in the theme, the core provides defaults itself.

From the docs page: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/adding-regions-to-a-theme

> **Default Regions**:
>
> `page.header`: Items for the header region.
>
> `page.primary_menu`: Items for the primary menu region.
>
> `page.secondary_menu`: Items for the secondary menu region.
>
> `page.highlighted`: Items for the highlighted content region.
>
> `page.help`: Dynamic help text, mostly for admin pages.
>
> `page.content`: The main content of the current page.
>
> `page.sidebar_first`: Items for the first sidebar.
>
> `page.sidebar_second`: Items for the second sidebar.
>
> `page.footer`: Items for the footer region.
>
> `page.breadcrumb`: Items for the breadcrumb region.
>
> **If your theme does not declare any regions Drupal will assume this set
>   of defaults.** These regions correspond with what the default
>   core/modules/system/templates/page.html.twig file expects, as well as
>   two hidden regions, `page_top`, and `page_bottom` - you don't need to
>   declare these final two if you override the defaults, however the `{{
>   page_top }}` and `{{ page_bottom }}` Twig variables should be retained
>   in the html.html.twig template.

Answer (score 4):

After some more research I finally found it [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/adding-regions-to-a-theme). The following is a quote of the section explaining how it works.

> ### Default Regions
>
> See the [page.html.twig documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21templates%21page.html.twig/8) for a list of default regions.
>
> 1. page.header
> 2. page.primary_menu
> 3. page.secondary_menu
> 4. page.highlighted
> 5. page.help (dynamic help text, mostly for admin pages)
> 6. page.content (main content of current page)
> 7. page.sidebar_first
> 8. page.sidebar_second
> 9. page.footer
> 10. page.breadcrumb
>
> If your theme does not declare any regions Drupal will assume this set of defaults. These regions correspond with what the default core/modules/system/templates/page.html.twig file expects, as well as two hidden regions, page_top, and page_bottom - you don't need to declare these final two if you override the defaults, however the {{ page_top }} and {{ page_bottom }} Twig variables should be retained in the html.html.twig template.